# Lua print(table) em string (pegando todos seus valores)

Tags: lua, lua-table

Criei um sistema rapidinho pra testar uma nova variável, mas não sei como faço pra ele imprimir os usuários inseridos na tabela, e quando vou dar `print` ele mostra isto: `table: 0035AE18`

Meu código:

```
Conta = {balance = 0}
Contas = {}
Senhas = {}
Inicial = 5000
function Conta:withdraw (v)
Conta.Balance = Conta.Balance - v
end

function Login()
io.write("Digite seu Usuario\n")
usuariol = io.read()
io.write("Digite sua senha\n")
senhal = io.read()

for i=0, #Contas do
for j=0, #Senhas do
if usuariol == Contas[i] and senhal == Senhas[j] then
io.write("Logado com sucesso!")
Cadastro()
end
end
end
end

function Cadastro()
io.write("Ola, seja bem vindo ao sistema de Banco 1.0 By Charles \n")
io.write("Deseja criar uma conta? \n")
resposta = io.read()

if resposta == "sim" or resposta == "Sim" then
io.write("Ok, informe seu nome de usuario \n")
usuario = io.read()
io.write("Informe sua senha \n")
senha = io.read()
io.write("Aguarde um instante!\n")
if #Contas == 0 and #Senhas == 0 then
table.insert(Contas, 1, usuario)
table.insert(Senhas, 1, senha)
else
table.insert(Contas, usuario)
table.insert(Senhas, senha)
end
Login()

elseif resposta == "tabela" then
print(#Contas)
print(#Senhas)
end
end

Cadastro()
```

O sistema funciona assim: ele cria a conta, depois você loga nele volta pra criação de conta.

Vamos supor criei 3 contas e depois na parte "você deseja criar conta" eu digitar "tabela" ele vai me mostrar o número de contas e senhas criadas.

Mas eu quero exibi-las não em tamanho capacidade e sim por *string*. Ex:

```
t = {'teste'}
print(t)
```

Console:

> table: teste

Comment: Havia um voto para desfazer a exclusão da sua pergunta, o que indica que provavelmente alguém quer respondê-la. Por isso, desfiz a exclusão. Por favor me avise caso isso não te agrade. Obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Acho que é isto que você quer:

```
Conta = {balance = 0}
Contas = {}
Senhas = {}
Inicial = 5000
function Conta:withdraw (v)
    Conta.Balance = Conta.Balance - v
end

function Login()
    io.write("Digite seu Usuario\n")
    usuariol = io.read()
    io.write("Digite sua senha\n")
    senhal = io.read()

    for i=0, #Contas do
        for j=0, #Senhas do
            if usuariol == Contas[i] and senhal == Senhas[j] then
                io.write("Logado com sucesso!")
                Cadastro()
            end
        end
    end
end

function Cadastro()
    io.write("Ola, seja bem vindo ao sistema de Banco 1.0 By Charles \n")
    io.write("Deseja criar uma conta? \n")
    resposta = io.read()

    if resposta == "sim" or resposta == "Sim" then
        io.write("Ok, informe seu nome de usuario \n")
        usuario = io.read()
        io.write("Informe sua senha \n")
        senha = io.read()
        io.write("Aguarde um instante!\n")
        if #Contas == 0 and #Senhas == 0 then
            table.insert(Contas, 1, usuario)
            table.insert(Senhas, 1, senha)
        else
            table.insert(Contas, usuario)
            table.insert(Senhas, senha)
        end
        Login()

    elseif resposta == "tabela" then
        for i,v in ipairs(Contas) do
            print(v)
        end
        for i,v in ipairs(Senhas) do
            print(v)
        end
    end
end

Cadastro()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/uyLP9e). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TraverseTable). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TraverseTable.lua).

Eu usei a técnica mais recomendada para varrer todo *array* mas você poderia usar a mesma que usou para verificar se usuário e senha estão cadastrados.

Acho que deveria rever a forma como estes dados estão armazenados.

Seu código vai trazer problemas de memória (falando a grosso modo) na forma como ele está organizado.

Existem alguns outros problemas mas acho que você ainda vai mexer bastante nele.